# Kubernetes on GCE: Ingress Timeout Configuration

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I'm running Kubernetes on Google Compute Engine (GCE). I have an Ingress set up. Everything works perfectly except when I upload large files, the L7 HTTPS Load Balancer terminates the connection after 30 seconds. I know that I can bump this up manually in the "Backend Service", but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this from the Ingress spec. I worry that my manual tweak will get changed back to 30s later on.

The nginx ingress controller has a number of annotations that can be used to configure nginx. Does the GCE L7 Load Balancer have something similar?

Comment: Yes, it has similar annotations. Quicker then finding these is probably to configure it through the Google Cloud Console

Comment: I'm worried that if I change something manually, the changes will be overwritten next time I change my ingress spec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can now be configured within GKE, by using a custom resource `BackendConfig`.

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-bconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 60
```

And then configuring your `Service` to use this configuration with an annotation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"my-bconfig"}}'
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  .... other fields
```

See [Configuring a backend service through Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service)

Comment: I had ajax requests taking more than 30 secs, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for the solution to this problem, `timeout` and other settings (e.g. enable CDN) can only be configured manually at the moment.

[Follow this `kubernetes/ingress-gce` issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/28) for the latest updates on a long-term solution.