# Custom Container scaling implementation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, load-balancing, google-cloud-run

I'm making a realtime multiplayer game and I have an idea on how to structure the backend, but I don't even know if its possible, let alone how to build and deploy it. Basically I want to deploy my backend as a container to cloud run but instead of syncing data through a database common to all instances I want to store the game data locally in each instance and just connect players in the same game to the same instance. Essentially I would need a custom load balancer and scaling logic. I haven't been able to find any useful material on this topic so any help/input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to do on Kubernetes, but I doubt that this can be easily done on Google Cloud Run. Your game-pod is essentially *stateful* workload and does not fit well on Google Cloud Run, but you can run this on Kubernetes as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

> Essentially I would need a custom load balancer and scaling logic.

Yes. For this you need to use an [UDP/TCP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-parameters) and you most likely need to deploy [custom configuration to allow longer connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44601191/kubernetes-on-gce-ingress-timeout-configuration/59671993#59671993) than default. This network load balancer will forward traffic to your *custom load balancer* - probably running as a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

### Custom Load Balancer - Sharding Proxy

What you need as *custom load balancer* is a [Sharding Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675990/sharded-load-balancing-for-stateful-services-in-kubernetes/58678622#58678622) that can forward traffic to correct Game Session Pod and potentially also to scale up to more Game Session Pods. See the answer to [Sharded load balancing for stateful services in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675990/sharded-load-balancing-for-stateful-services-in-kubernetes/58678622#58678622) for more info on this.

### Game Session App

The app that handles the Game Session need to be deployed as a `StatefulSet` so that they get an *unique network identity* e.g. `game-session-0`, `game-session-1` and `game-session-2` - so that your *custom load balancer* can use logic to direct the traffic to correct Game Session Pod.

> I want to store the game data locally in each instance and just connect players in the same game to the same instance.

This is possible, use a volume of type [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir).

### Game Server Example on GKE

For an extensive example of this type of deployment, see [Running dedicated game servers in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/running-dedicated-game-servers-in-kubernetes-engine)